# Steps for creating an AWS AMI from a brand new Ubuntu image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, iso

I'm digging into AWS for the first time, and am trying to figure out how to take a "brand new" Ubuntu ISO, preconfigure it, and then turn it into an AMI. There are currently many other Ubuntu-based AMIs that I could use, but:

- For one, I don't fully *trust* them 100%, especially with the sensitive business data that I'll be serving from my EC2 instances; and
- I'd like to personally harden my Ubuntu instances myself; and
- In general, I'd just like to get the "*full AWS admin experience*", which to me includes defining every detail of the AMI that is used to spin up new EC2 instances from.

The latest stable version of [Ubuntu Server is 14.04.1 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server).

So I ask: **How do I create a new AMI from an Ubuntu ISO, and then customize that AMI such that all new EC2 instances spawned from that AMI behave the way I want?**

Answer (score 1):

Read:

http://www.idevelopment.info/data/AWS/AWS_Tips/AWS_Management/AWS_10.shtml

https://jeevanullas.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/creating-your-own-ami-for-amazon-ec2/

Above articles should give you a starting point for creating your own AMI.